# Netty - The Proper Way to Maintain Map of Channels outside of Handlers

Tags: java, netty

Our scenario is as follow:

1. There's a TCP server written using Netty.
2. There are multiple clients establishing a connection to the server.
3. After establishing the connection, messages can be sent in the two direction.

To be able to deliver messages to correct recipients I need to maintain channel outside of handlers. I'm aware of `ChannelGroup` which let me easily implement a broadcast server (one message to all clients).

Now the requirement is how to write to specific channel.
I'm thinking to have a `ChannelGroup` and enrich it with client-specific id map (with a `Map<ClientId, ChannelId>` mapping client-id to channel-id). This way having a client-id, I can easily get the channel and write to it.

Now my question is:

1. Generally what is the different between writing via `ChannelHandlerContext` and via `Channel`? (since `ChannelGroup` gives me the `Channel` not `ChannelHandlerContext`).
2. Is it a bad idea to maintain the group of `ChannelHandlerContext`? (in other words, why don't we have `ChannelHandlerContextGroup`)?
3. Any other suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The difference between operation on a Channel vs ChannelHandler context is that when using for example `Channel.write(...)` it will start to traverse the while `ChannelPipeline` (from the tail to the head), while using `ChannelHandlerContext.write(...)` it will start the traversal of the `ChannelPipeline` from the given `ChannelHandlerContext` which belongs to a specific position in the `ChannelPipeline` as it is "related" to the `ChannelHandler` that was added before.

2) It is not a bad idea but most of the times users that use `ChannelGroup` want to to use `Channel.write(...)` (see above)

3) Either using `ChannelGroup` or `Map` is fine. When using a `Map` just ensure you will remove the `Channel` / `ChannelHandlerContext` from the `Map` once the `Channel` is closed.